# Problem getting a object value inside array : TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Probably I'm doing something wrong, I'm very new in react. So, I just need to get the value of a property of the product object.

```
function Products() {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        api.get('/product/list')
            .then(response => {
                setProducts((response.data))
            })
    }, [])


    return (
            <div className="main">
                  <div id="landings">
                   {console.log(products)}
                </div>
            </div>
    );
}

export default Products;
```

When I use the `console.log(products[0])`, I got this:

[image: Console]

But, if I try to get a property of the object, like that: `console.log(products[0].name)`

I got the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably a combination of [how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and [is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: Please provide log output as text, not as a link to a picture of text. You can also do yourself a favor and use `console.log(JSON.stringify(products, null, 2))` to get a printout of the object at the time of evaluation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to understand how the React Hooks works.

The reason for this behavior is when this component is mounted, **products** is initialized with the value [] since you used useState React Hook, and then rendering happens.

Till that time

- The Value of **products is []**
- The value of **products[0] is undefined**.

That's the reason why console.log(products[0].name) says **"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"**

Once the 1st render completes the **useEffect** hook comes into the picture since it is serving the behavior of **componentDidMount** here and performs the API call to get **products** data and assign it to products once response comes.

**You should always ensure that you are not trying to access key from the undefined objects**

Here, instead of using console.log(products[0].name) use
**{products && products[0] && console.log(products[0].name)}**

this will keep your code from breaking.

For a better understanding of how React Hooks works read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html
and since you are very new to React understand the lifecycle of React from here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Hope you get the idea..
Happy Coding!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Initially you get empty array, once fetch the data you receive non empty array
so you could simply hide this errors by

```
return (
  <div className="main">
    {products.length && <div id="landings">{console.log(products)}</div>}
  </div>
);
```

or

```
return (
  <div className="main">
    <div id="landings">
      {products.map((product) => (
        <span key={product.id}>{product.name}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```